# How to create a 4 boxes square with HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to understand how to build a 4 boxes square like the one on the printscreen. I've found that layout on Apple's website and I pretty like it!

I tried with bootstrap and flexbox. I think flexbox is a better solution, but I didn't find a way to reproduce this layout.

Anybody can help me to figure out how to create that layout?

[image: Layout's screencap]

Comment: Where is your code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D I’m sorry, it was my first post and I was kind of confused. Next time I’ll show my attempts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use bootstrap, this is easily doable.

```css
.noMargin {
  margin: 0px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
}

.four {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row noMargin">
    <div class="col one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="col two">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row noMargin">
    <div class="col three">
      three
    </div>
    <div class="col four">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you would like to do pure html/css:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row div {
  width: 50%;
}

.noMargin {
  margin: 0px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
}

.four {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row noMargin">
  <div class="one">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    two
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row noMargin">
  <div class="three">
    three
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Seems to do the trick. I’ll try it this evening and let you know :)

Comment: @Max glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Box</title>
    <style>
        #div1{
            height:300px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:red;
            margin:0;
            }
        #div2{
            height:300px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:green;
            position:relative;
            left:320px;
            bottom:300px;
            }
         #div3{
            height:300px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:yellow;
            position:relative;
            bottom:280px;
            }
        #div4{
            height:300px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:blue;
            position:relative;
            left:320px;
            bottom:580px;
            }
            
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div1">
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
    </div>

    <div id="div4"> 
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Don't use absolute values in CSS...** use %, rem, em or other properties. In this case you can use flex-box or grid containers.